# Why don't need to parameterize with generic inner class?

Tags: java, generics, inner-classes

Trying to write a custom ( but well known) stack generic implementation with a custom linked list. But the algorithm is not the point. My question is, why don't need to parameterize

```
class Node<T>
```

as well as declare

```
Node <T> top;  //pointer to next node
```

Will it be redundant? Why? Or may be need to use another character e.g. `<U>`?

```
public class Stack<T> {
        //T is the type parameter
        Node top; //topmost element of stack

        //defines each node of stack
        class Node{
           T value; //value of each node
           Node next;  //pointer to next node

           public Node(T value){
             this.value=value;  //initializing
             next=null;
           }
        }
        //This function pushes new element
        public void push(T value){
         Node current=new Node(value);
         if(isEmpty())
            top=current; //if empty stack
         else{
            current.next=top;
            top=current;
         }
        }
        //This function pops topmost element
        public T pop(){
         T value=null;
         if(!isEmpty()){
             top=top.next;
             value=top.value;
         }
         return value;  //returning popped value
        }
```

Comment: Since it's a non-static class it has access to the `T` of the enclosing class. If you _were_ to have `Node<T>` then the `T` of `Node` would be a _different_ `T` than the one associated with `Stack<T>` (i.e. the inner class' `T` would hide the outer class' `T`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will it be redundant?

Yes.

> Why?

Since `Node` is declared as an inner class of the `Stack`, the variable `T` is in scope in `Node`, and can be used as needed.

> Or may be need to use another character e.g. `<U>`?

If you needed to declare a distinct type variable, you could do that.  (Indeed you probably should use a different variable name.) It might look like this:

```
public class Stack<T> {

    Node<T> top;                               // CHANGE HERE

     class Node<U> {                           // CHANGE HERE
        U value;                               // CHANGE HERE
        Node<U> next;                          // CHANGE HERE

        public Node(U value) {                 // CHANGE HERE
            this.value = value;
            next = null;
        }
    }

    public void push(T value) {
        Node<T> current = new Node<>(value);   // CHANGE HERE
        if (isEmpty())
            top = current;
        else {
            current.next = top;
            top = current;
        }
    }

    public T pop() {
        T value = null;
        if (!isEmpty()) {
            top = top.next;
            value = top.value;
        }
        return value;
    }
```

This illustrates that adding the extra type variable results in more code, and doesn't improve readability.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the `Node` class here isn't `static`. This means that each **instance** of `Stack` has its own `Node` class. Like any other member, it can access its enclosing class' `T`.

Comment: Why don't need Node <T> top?

Comment: See last sentence.

Comment: can access and what? The real answer is:  then the T of Node would be a different T than the one associated with Stack<T>

Answer (score 1):

If your Node class was its own top level class (in its own .java file), then it would need a generic parameter as you are expecting it to have. And I would recommend you do this.

But, because it’s an (non-static) inner class of Stack, it has access to everything in the Stack *instance*, including all generic information.